# How do you implement your own authentication with ActiveAdmin without Devise? ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

According to the [ActiveAdmin documentation](https://activeadmin.info/1-general-configuration.html#authentication) you only have to create `authenticate_admin_user!` and `current_admin_user` methods to create authentication. I did that, provided the correct password, but it gives me an error page. What else is required?

`application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def authenticate_admin_user!
    puts session[:user].inspect
    redirect_to login_path unless session[:user] && session[:user]["admin"] == true
  end

  def current_admin_user
    session[:user]
  end

end
```

`config/initalizers/active_admin.rb`

```
  # == User Authentication
  #
  # Active Admin will automatically call an authentication
  # method in a before filter of all controller actions to
  # ensure that there is a currently logged in admin user.
  #
  # This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls
  # within the application controller.
  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!

  # == Current User
  #
  # Active Admin will associate actions with the current
  # user performing them.
  #
  # This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls
  # (within the application controller) to return the currently logged in user.
  config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
```

`index_controller.rb`

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
  def login_post
    if Digest::SHA256.base64digest(params[:password]) == "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx="
      session[:user] = {"admin" => true}
      redirect_to admin_root_path
    else
      flash.now.alert = 'Invalid password.'
      render :login
    end
```

Now it gives the error

```
Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-05 16:37:02 -0400
Processing by Admin::DashboardController#index as HTML
{"admin"=>true}
  Rendering C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.3.0/app/views/active_admin/page/index.html.arb
  Rendered C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.3.0/app/views/active_admin/page/index.html.arb (3476.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3882ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `destroy_admin_user_session_path' for "        <ul class=\"header-item tabs\" id=\"utility_nav\"></ul>\n":ActiveAdmin::Views::TabbedNavigation):
    1: insert_tag active_admin_application.view_factory["page"]

arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element.rb:182:in `method_missing'
```

ActiveAdmin loads fine with `config.authentication_method` and `config.current_user_method` commented.

Rails 5.0.7, ActiveAdmin 1.3.0

Comment: You also need to change `config.logout_link_path` in `config/initalizers/active_admin.rb`

Comment: @chloe I am stuck in similar problems as you and your questions and answers are helping me :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding

`routes.rb`

```
get :logout, controller: :index, as: :destroy_admin_user_session
```

`index_controller.rb`

```
  def logout
    reset_session
    redirect_to :root
  end
```